# Software used to create the schematic diagram

Tags: draw, software-design, langchain

Was learning langchain and landed on this beautiful blog.

[Langchain Tutorial](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/langchain-tutorial-1-build-an-llm-powered-app-in-18-lines-of-code/44355)

Is there any software people use to make this type of schematic diagram?

[image]

Spent 3 hours finding this ... one leads was https://star-history.com/ but it just creates a graph plot. Found https://excalidraw.com/ but still not quite there. Appreciate the help.